# How to play video element on iOS Safari after swipe user interaction?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, mobile-safari

Considering the [limitations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4) imposed by iOS Safari about the play/load call on a video element I use to initiate it at the first user `touchend` with a *preplay* action (`play()` followed by `pause()`). From that time I can *play* with the video as I want (this solution is partially described [here](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/ios9-web-audio/)).

The problem I encountered is a failed *preplay* (any next call to `play()` will be ignored) when the first `touchend` follows a swipe/drag interaction.

There is a way to let it works also with a swipe? or there is a reliable way to detect if the *preplay* was succeeded?

Comment: Have you've been able to solve this?. I am having the same problem. cannot use `play()` from `touchend` when it is the end of a swipe

Comment: Unfortunately not. The ux should be thought differently, forcing the user to click a button for some reason (eg. "Welcome! bla bla bla." and a "continue" button).

Comment: tx, Have you found a resource which confirms touchend/play does not work after a swipe?